# Running remote commands in background

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I created a PowerShell script that creates a remote session to Windows hosts running various Windows and PowerShell versions (including 2.0!) to execute a script block, using a command like:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $my_session1 -ScriptBlock { ... } -Args
```

I need to ensure that the script block can terminate even if the session terminates for any reason, maybe because the PC I use to issue the command crashes due to a power failure.

How can I ensure that the script block completes? Is there any way to run it in background, in a separate process or in any other way so that it can survive the closure of the session?

None of the solutions I found works with PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Use a scheduled task. There are no cmdlets for creating those in PowerShell 2.0, but you can use schtasks.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke command has a *-InDisconnectedSession* parameter which will help you to run the remote session in disconnected mode and further you can put that as *-AsJob* like:

```
Invoke-Command -InDisconnectedSession $yoursession -scriptblock{} -Args -AsJob
```

Hope it gives you a new direction.

Comment: `-InDisconnectedSession` is not available in PowerShell 2.0. I haven't tested if it works from a host with a later version of PowerShell invoking it in an earlier version, but I doubt it. (If it does, that's worth documenting.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I think I have tested this scenario and I have documented I think in the documentation of Powershell in SO.